# set env for sshfs

Tags: python, environment-variables, sshfs

`sshfs` fails mounting if the remote host doesn't support the local locale (LC_ALL). Goolge search pointed me to [www.knoppixforum.de](http://www.knoppixforum.de/knoppix-forum-deutsch/netzwerk/thread4766/knoppix-6-4-ssh-funktioniert-sshfs-nicht.html) on how to handle this problem on bash.

But I need to call `sshfs` from `python`. The (failing) command looks like:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(['sshfs', 'HOST:~/SRC', '~/DST'])
```

An other search pointed me to ['Set locale encoding in python'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11205786). And so I assumed it should look like:

```
import os, subprocess
env = os.environ.copy()
env['LC_ALL'] = 'en_US.UTF-8'
subprocess.check_call(['sshfs', 'HOST:~/SRC', '~/DST'], env = env)
```

But that doesn't work neither. I reckon it fails because sshfs fork an new process for ssh which don't adept my env variable?

Error message is always: `remote host has disconnected`

Comment: (1) If you set the environment variable and run the command from bash, does it work?  (2) If you set `env` as in your second code snippet, and run just `subprocess.check_call(['env'], env=env)`, do you see `LC_ALL` in the output?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? There may be easier alternatives for solving your problem.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: (1) yes that works (2) that also produce excepted output. Even `subprocess.check_call(['locale'], env=env)` shows correct locale. @PedroRomano: I use sshfs to provide fileaccess to GUI and take_snapshot process of [BackInTime](https://launchpad.net/backintime) in [sshtools.py line 77](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~germar/backintime/ssh/view/head:/common/sshtools.py)

Comment: Would using [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) for the remote file system access be an option, instead of mounting it locally with fuse sshfs?

Comment: paramiko would have caused massive changes all over BackinTime's code because BIT uses lots of local commands on its snapshot-path. So I decided to rather create a mount-framework and use sshfs to simply mount remote path (other services will follow). The real backup is done with rsync over ssh and doesn't affect sshfs but for pre- and post-commands we need local access. It does work quite nice and I only need to fix some bugs (like this one) before merging with main trunk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haha, I fooled my self! My above approach does work. Except that 'en_US.UTF-8' is not available on the machine that I used for testing. During testing on bash I used 'de_DE.UTF-8' before.

With LC_ALL='C' everything work like expected. So the right solution would be:

```
import os, subprocess
env = os.environ.copy()
env['LC_ALL'] = 'C'
subprocess.check_call(['sshfs', 'HOST:~/SRC', '~/DST'], env = env)
```